# How to draw circle in front of an object in 2d on Javascript & HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I'm struggling with the maths on this one.  I have an arrow that moves randomly around the canvas. It rotates smoothly and moves towards the next X/Y position. Great. How can I make my circle object always appear just in front of the arrow; like as if the arrow is holding the circle on it's tip.

Here is my code:

```
player.prototype.draw = function (w, h, ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#E50000';

    if (this.XPercent !== 0 && this.YPercent !== 0) {
        // ** moves at correct angle (no rotation involved)

        // Get the difference between the points
        var tx = this.nextXPercent - this.XPercent;
        var ty = this.nextYPercent - this.YPercent;

        // Add the x and y areas then get the square root
        var dist = Math.sqrt(tx * tx + ty * ty);
        var newX = (tx / dist) * 0.1;
        var newY = (ty / dist) * 0.1;
        this.XPercent = this.XPercent + (isNaN(newX) ? 0 : newX);
        this.YPercent = this.YPercent + (isNaN(newY) ? 0 : newY);
    }

    var currentX = (w / 100) * this.XPercent;
    var currentY = (h / 100) * this.YPercent;

    ctx.translate(currentX - (playerWidth / 2), currentY);
    currentX = (playerWidth / 2);
    currentY = 0;

    // now rotate smoothly
    ctx.rotate(this.getRotation2(w, h, ctx) * Math.PI / 180);

    ctx.moveTo(currentX, currentY);
    ctx.lineTo(currentX - playerWidth, currentY - (playerHeight / 2));
    ctx.lineTo(currentX - playerWidth, currentY + (playerHeight / 2));
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.restore();
    ctx.closePath();
};
```

The above moves the arrow around with no rotation.  My rotation method is as follows:

```
player.prototype.getRotation2 = function (w, h, ctx) {
    var y2 = this.nextYPercent;
    var y1 = this.YPercent.toFixed(0);
    var x2 = this.nextXPercent;
    var x1 = this.XPercent.toFixed(0);

    if (x1 == x2 && y2 == y1) {
        return this.angle;
    }

    var Xdiff = y2 - y1;
    var Ydiff = x2 - x1;

    this.angle %= 360;
    var rads = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
    var targetAngle = rads * (180 / Math.PI);
    targetAngle = (targetAngle + 360) % 360;

    if (this.angle != targetAngle) {
        var netAngle = (this.angle - targetAngle + 360) % 360;
        var delta = Math.min(Math.abs(netAngle - 360), netAngle, 5);

        var sign = (netAngle - 180) >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
        this.angle += sign * delta + 360;
        this.angle %= 360;

        if (this.hasBall) {
            // This is where we should position the circle at correct angle
            gameBall.XPercent = this.XPercent + ???
            gameBall.YPercent = this.YPercent + ???
        }
    }

    return this.angle;
};
```

Comment: Keep it simple ... Create your arrow **with a circle on the tip** on a second canvas and use `context.drawImage(theSecondCanvas,x,y)` to draw that pre-circled arrow onto the main canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just continue using the transformation you have for the arrow and go "right" to draw the ball at the end of the arrow.

I would suggest separating the drawing and transformation operations. This way you can draw the arrow is a single way without worrying about its location or rotation. The ball can be added using a flag as argument to the method.

**Example**

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), radius = 7;

function drawShape() {
  // Always draw with (0,0) as basis, this will rotate at tail.
  // If rotate at head, just offset the values so head is at (0,0)
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0); 
  ctx.lineTo(50, 0);
  ctx.moveTo(50, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(40, -5);
  ctx.lineTo(40, 5);
  ctx.fill();
  
  // add circle at tip
  ctx.moveTo(60 + radius, 0);
  ctx.arc(60, 0, radius, 0, 6.28);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// just to add action for the demo
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect(),
      x = e.clientX - rect.left,
      y = e.clientY - rect.top,
      dx = x - c.width*0.5,
      dy = y - c.height*0.5,
      a = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
  
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height)
  ctx.translate(c.width*0.5, c.height*0.5);
  ctx.rotate(a);
  drawShape();
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

To Pace a object via polar coordinates use the trig functions cos and sin.

for example

```
var distance = 100;
var angle = 4; // angle in radians

var x = Math.cos(angle) * distance;
var y = Math.sin(angle) * distance;
```

The x and y is what you add to the arrow coord.