# How to add rectangle/arrow to my canvas line?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this code to show wind direction on html canvas:

```
var x, y, r, ctx, radians;

  ctx = window.compass.getContext("2d");

  radians = 0.0174533 * (10 - 90);
  x = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
  y = ctx.canvas.height / 2;
  r = x * 0.8;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height );
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red"
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
  ctx.lineCap = 'square';
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 4;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 4;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
  ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;

  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + r * Math.cos(radians), y + r * Math.sin(radians));
  ctx.stroke();
```

I want to add arrowhead to the start point of the line, i.e

x = ctx.canvas.width / 2;
  y = ctx.canvas.height / 2;

how can I do this?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471353/how-to-draw-circle-in-front-of-an-object-in-2d-on-javascript-html5-canvas/37473030#37473030) as a reference. Just follow the instructions for rotation around head and replace circle with an arrow.

Comment: it is obtusely hard in html canvas

Comment: Seems so.. best thing I can come up with is to draw a circle to my starting point which is static and doesn't change as my line changes. Not very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a reusable wind-arrow is fairly straightforward:**

1. Create your shadowed arrow on an in-memory canvas:

   ```
   var memCanvas=document.createElement('canvas')
   ```
2. Draw the in-memory canvas onto the visible canvas:

   ```
   ctx.drawImage(memCanvas,x,y);
   ```

[image][image]

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var angle=0;

var arrow=makeArrow(100,10,20,20,'red',4);

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate(time){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    drawArrow(cx,cy,angle);
    angle+=Math.PI/180;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function drawArrow(cx,cy,radianAngle){
    ctx.translate(cx,cy);
    ctx.rotate(radianAngle);
    ctx.drawImage(arrow,-arrow.width/2,-arrow.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(-radianAngle);
    ctx.translate(-cx,-cy);
}

function makeArrow(length,lineHeight,arrowLength,arrowHeight,fillcolor,shadowoffset){
    var lineTop=(arrowHeight-lineHeight)/2;
    var arrowLeft=length-arrowLength;
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
    c.width=length+shadowoffset;
    c.height=arrowHeight+shadowoffset;

    ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowoffset;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = shadowoffset;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
    ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
      
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,lineTop);
    ctx.lineTo(arrowLeft,lineTop);
    ctx.lineTo(arrowLeft,0);
    ctx.lineTo(length,arrowHeight/2);
    ctx.lineTo(arrowLeft,arrowHeight);
    ctx.lineTo(arrowLeft,lineTop+lineHeight);
    ctx.lineTo(0,lineTop+lineHeight);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle=fillcolor;
    ctx.fill();
    return(c);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; padding:10px; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```